# Selecting dataframe from list by name

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to select a dataframe from a list by part of a name (as condition)? For example, I would like to return row 2 (index 1) from the following df, out of df_list, by the last two letters 'BA';

```
df_HO_BA = pd.DataFrame(
        {'bin': [0,3,2],
        'LG': ['AR1', 'PO1', 'RU1']})

    LG  bin
0  AR1    0
1  PO1    3
2  RU1    2

df_list = [df_HO_BA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the dataframes in a dictionary instead and use a function to call the appropriate dataframe based upon a given keyword contained within the dataframe's name:

```
df_HO_BA = pd.DataFrame(
        {'bin': [0,3,2],
        'LG': ['AR1', 'PO1', 'RU1']})

df_dic = {'df_HO_BA':df_HO_BA}

def return_df(dic, keyword):
    for key in dic.keys():
        if keyword in key:
            return df_dic[key]
        else:
            raise Exception('keyword "{0}" not found in any dataframe names'.format(keyword))

new_df = return_df(df_dic, 'BA')
print new_df

OUT:
LG  bin
0  AR1    0
1  PO1    3
2  RU1    2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, wasn't fully clear. I need to select by part of the name. I'll adjust the question

Comment: Updated per your feedback

Comment: Thanks, deleted the comment though. Guess these people can't be helped anyway.